# Is there a way to delete a plone site in the debug console?

Tags: plone, zope

I want to remove a Plone site from a Zope instance using the debug console. The next code is an example of how it could be.

```
$ bin/instance debug
>>> del(app.plone)
```

I think that perhaps a similar functionality exists. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the ObjectManager API:

```
app.manage_delObjects(['plone'])
```

and make sure you commit the transaction, of course.

Zope 2.12 and newer implement the `__delitem__` special method and:

```
del app['plone']
```

also works.

Comment: Backticks before and after :-) `__delitem__`; or two backslashes at the starting underscores for plaintext \_\_delitem__.